# jBPM - Access signal event data?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, business-process-management, bpmn

I am new to jBPM and I seem to lose something fundamental. I cannot seem to find any descent tutorial on how to make an actual process work from a developer's point of view. Therefore, I follow the official [jBPM 6.1 user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/). I have setup the process shown in the screenshot
[image]

As you can see, the process is very simple. A signal event is raised and the data given to this signal event are mapped to the `IncomingData` object. In the following script task, I write a message to the console and try to write the `IncomingData` object's testing property data content to test the handling of event's data.

I test my process using a unit test:

```
@Test
public void testProcess() {
    RuntimeManager manager = createRuntimeManager("workflow.bpmn");
    RuntimeEngine engine = getRuntimeEngine(null);
    KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();

    ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess("testing.OA");

    IncomingData dataObject = new IncomingData();
    dataObject.testProperty = "Testing data 2";
    ksession.signalEvent("StartSignalWithData", dataObject, processInstance.getId());


    // check whether the process instance has completed successfully
    assertProcessInstanceCompleted(processInstance.getId(), ksession);

    manager.disposeRuntimeEngine(engine);
    manager.close();

}
```

However, all I get in the console output is the message `Script task logging null`. Could you please explain where am I wrong?

1. I am pretty confident that in my unit test, I pass the event data using the right procedure as indicated [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMBPMN2.html#d0e3196). I don't believe the problem is there...
2. Is the problem in the modelling of the process? I have created the data object `IncomingData` which I believed it could hold the data of the event. EDIT:I have also mapped the signal incoming data to the respective data object (see the next screenshot). Is something wrong with that?

[image]

3. Am I doing something wrong while calling the `IncomingData` object in the script task? Should I use the `kcontext` or something?

Could you by any chance point me to a tutorial for jBPM 6.1 or something?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: PS. You can find my bpmn file in [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikbjksgx7y6uj7n/workflow.bpmn?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. When I tried to debug more carefully, I noticed that the process' script task executes when the process starts through the call `ksession.startProcess("testing.OA")` **before the raise of the event** which is done through the `ksession.signalEvent`. This would naturally leed to a null `IncomingData` object when the process is executed.

Answer (score 0):

In the start event you also need to create a mapping, that will map the signal data to a variable of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have done that. Please see my edited answer... Could you suggest a tutorial or something?